# Easiest way to test email notifications locally?

Tags: emails

I am making a forum website with email notifications. I need to test these email notifications locally. Ive only ever used MAMP so I dont have much experience setting up dev environments.

What's the easiest way to test Drupal's email notifications locally?  Can the Acquia stack do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can log the emails, which also brings some sanity to your inbox. Of cause there is a module for that (or two):

- [Maillogger](http://drupal.org/project/mail_logger)
- [Maillog / Mail Developer](http://drupal.org/project/maillog)

Comment: Thats a nice way round. Ideally id prefere emails to be sent but yourse is a close 2nd choice. Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/reroute_email is another module that will send the emails to a configured address rather than logging them.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Antix](http://antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTP-Impostor-an-SMTP-server-for-developers). It's easy to set up and works well to test out on a local Drupal install.

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of solutions is documented in the Drupal Community Documentation: [Managing Mail Handling for Development or Testing](https://www.drupal.org/node/201981).

Personally I prefer a combination of a local Postfix mail server, the [Reroute Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/reroute_email) module, and rerouting to a local mailbox. This has the advantage that you don't have to go through the trouble of setting up your local host to successfully send to external e-mail addresses without being rejected as a possible spammer. How to set it up:

1. Install postfix. The default configuration under Ubuntu will work for our purposes.
2. Make sure your relevant `php.ini` is set up to use postfix by containing these two lines. Contrary to the comments there, these settings are not just used on Win32 systems.

   ```
   SMTP = localhost
   smtp_port = 25
   ```
3. Install the Reroute Email module: `drush dl reroute_email && drush en reroute-email`.
4. In the configuration settings for Reroute Email, set the target addres to your Linux username (such as `matt`, no `@hostname.tld` part here). These e-mails arrive in your local mailbox in `/var/spool/` then.
5. Set up Thunderbird to fetch these e-mails: Go to "Edit → Account Settings → Add Other Account… → Type: Unix Mailspool (Movemail)" and use these settings:

   - "E-Mail Address": again use your Linux username (such as `matt`) but determine your hostname (`hostname` command) and add it  hostname behind in the format `username@hostname`.
   - "Your Name" and "Account Name": anything will work, this is just cosmetics.